# Julia-Set Code with C++ unclear

Tags: complex-numbers, numerical-methods, fractals, complex-dynamics

So, I'm working lately on a julia-set code with c++ and there are two formulas in this script. The first one is **x = x^2 - y^2 (+ re)** and the next one is **y = 2*x*y (+ im)**. I never read this formulas before and i don't know what they are supposed to calculate. Can somebody explain?

Comment: $(x+iy)^2 = x^2-y^2+2i xy$

Comment: What you posted is neither math nor C++ code, so it's hard to guess what the question is.

Comment: @user1952009 thanks!!! thats the answer to my question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the real and imaginary parts of the complex iteration

$$z_{n+1}={z_n}^2 + c$$

Derivation:

Let $z_n = a_n+b_ni$ and $c = x+yi$.

${z_n}^2 + c = (a_n + b_n i)^2+(x+yi) = {a_n}^2 - {b_n}^2+x+(2a_nb_n+y)i$